# How to add permissions in Django Rest Framework for specific requests

Tags: django, permissions, django-rest-framework

I am creating a class based api for a documentation app, but I want to add specific permissions to the post and patch definitions in my APIView. For example,

```
class DocumentList(APIView):

    def get(self,request,format=None):
         ... blah

    def post(self,request,format=None):
        only allow administrators to create new documents 
        ... blah
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[By default permissions are unrestricted](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions#setting-the-permission-policy). In your `settings.py` you can specify a different set of defaults to where users have to be authenticated and have the correct Django model permission. You will need to specify a `model` attribute on your view class for the `DjangoModelPermissions` to take effect.

```
# settings.py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissions'
    )
}

# views.py
class DocumentList(APIView):
    model = Document
    ...
```

The `DjangoModelPermissions` permission map [can be found in the source](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/permissions.py#L84).

- GET, OPTIONS and HEAD don't require a permission but since we specified `IsAuthenticated` we're still requiring that
- POST maps to add
- PUT and PATCH map to change
- DELETE maps to delete

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did. Reference from the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#object-level-permissions)

Created permission class for the project

project/permissions.py

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Read permission - always allow for GET request
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        # Write permissions - only if authenticated
        return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated()
```

Now use this PermissionClass in the view

```
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, ))
class ShopViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     queryset = Shop.objects.all()
     serializer_class = ShopSerializer
```

Comment: we can also set **permission_classes** attribute in ShopViewSet